# Deactivating nginx Service

Tags: node.js, nginx

We are trying to set up cncjs on a pi that had previously used as a robo pi and ran nginx. We tried "sudo /etc/init.d/nginx stop" but this did not work. We were then advised to use “service nginx stop” but it is asking for a password we don't have. anyway to get around this password? 
Or maybe a better way to make cncjs work?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `sudo` works enter the command `sudo su`.

Then enter the command `service nginx stop`.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that this solution will not "deactivate" the service, but only stop it. Restarting the RPi will restart the service again.

Comment: Reasonable point, but since "deactivate" does not have an objective technical meaning in this context, it is not clear from the question what the goal is beyond "stopping" it, which is repeated several times in the question.

Comment: My bad; to clarify we would like to deactivate it w/o it restarting when the pi restarts. we don't plan on restarting the Pi but its in a high school work shop so it will definitely get restarted on accident.

Comment: @tw21 Try `sudo systemctl disable nginx`